# Subversion svn+http access

Tags: svn

Currently we access our repo via svn:\, but recently the need to access a restricted set of files via http:// has arisen.
We have certain raw html and txt files which we need to display directly from the repo using http://.

Our repo is hosted by the svnserve process on a windows server and ALL access is on an INTRANET so there's no major security risks, as it would have been the case if our repo was acsessible over the internet.

I was thinking about restricting access using svnauthaccess:

```
# deny all access to everything [svn:/]
* = 
# allow only read of 
[svn:/ProjX/trunk/Doc/some.txt]
[svn:/ProjY/trunk/Doc/info.html]
```

Is there any way to do this, without have to install Apache first?
Something like: http://svnserver:8080/svn/ProjX/trunk/Doc/some.txt

Kind regards
Garrett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so.  Svnserve speaks the Subversion protocol; it's not in the business of being a webserver.  That's why the mod_dav_svn plugin exists for Apache.

Fortunately, it's not at all difficult to set up; check out the relevant chapter of the Subversion book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html.  Once you get it running, you'll be able to do pretty much exactly what you said you'd like to do in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may also make use of hook svn scripts there you can define actions how system should respond on attempts of overwriting given subset of files.